# IronPython convert from Python String to SByte array

Tags: string, ironpython, arrays

for the usage of an external dll in IronPython I have to pass a string to a **char array** (char var[len]; in C++.NET). It seems to be expected to pass an SByte array.

If I try

```
myVarFromCLibrary = myPyString
```

I get

```
TypeError: expected Array[SByte], got str
```

There is very little information in the web. Up to now I found that I can apply something like this:

```
from System import Array
...
myCString = Array[System.SByte](myPyString)

myVarFromCLibrary = myCString
```

If I do so, I get an error like:

```
TypeError: expected SByte, got str
```

What is to do to get the right conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a workaround but no solution:

```
def strToCharArray(theCharArray,theString):
  asBytes = bytes(theString,'ascii')  
  for i in xrange(len(theString)):
    theCharArray[i] = ord(asBytes[i])
  theCharArray[len(asBytes)] = 0

def charArrayToStr(theCharArray):  
  chars = []
  i     = 0
  while theCharArray[i]>0: 
    chars.append(chr(theCharArray[i]))
    i += 1
  return "".join(chars)
```

This keeps my program running but is not the real solution